# How do I crop an image in opencv and python based on percentage

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I want to take an image and crop it by 75% from the center of the original image.  To be honest I'm at a bit of a loss on it.  I had thought about getting the original image size

```
height, width = image.shape
```

getting a percentage value and cropping:

```
cropped_y_start = int((height * 0.75))
cropped_y_end = int((height * 0.25))
cropped_x_start = int((width * 0.75))
cropped_x_end = int((width * 0.25))

print cropped_x_start
print cropped_x_end

crop_img = image[cropped_y_start:cropped_y_end, cropped_x_start:cropped_x_end]
```

There are multiple problems with this but the main one being its not based off the center of the image.  Any advice on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Here's an easy way to think about it... imagine some simple, but arbitrary dimensions for your image where the width and height are different so as not to get confused - let's go with 200x100 pixels. Now imagine what you mean with *"cropping by 75%"*. Now try your formulae and see if they come out correctly.

Comment: If you want to crop the height **by** 75%, you will need to remove 37.5% from the top and 37.5% from the bottom - meaning your new bottom will be 62.5% down from the old top.

Comment: If you want to crop the height **to** 75%, you will need to remove 12.5% from the top and 12.5% from the bottom, meaning your new bottom will be 87.5% down from the old top.

Answer (score 9):

A simple way is to first get your scaled width and height, and then crop from the image center to plus/minus the scaled width and height divided by 2.
Here is an example:

```py
import cv2

def crop_img(img, scale=1.0):
    center_x, center_y = img.shape[1] / 2, img.shape[0] / 2
    width_scaled, height_scaled = img.shape[1] * scale, img.shape[0] * scale
    left_x, right_x = center_x - width_scaled / 2, center_x + width_scaled / 2
    top_y, bottom_y = center_y - height_scaled / 2, center_y + height_scaled / 2
    img_cropped = img[int(top_y):int(bottom_y), int(left_x):int(right_x)]
    return img_cropped

img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg')
img_cropped = crop_img(img, 0.75)
```

Output:

Original

[image: Original]

Cropped by 75%

[image: Cropped by 75%]